# SQL Pattern to merge time series data into a single 'date' column

Tags: google-bigquery, etl, data-transform

I have some housing data imported into BigQuery and it looks like this -

### zip_code | date_1 | date_2 | date_3 ...

12345 | 01/01/00 | 01/08/00 | 01/15/00 ....

I would like to transform it into something like this in BQ:

### zip_code | date

12345 | 01/01/00
12345 | 01/08/00
12345 | 01/15/00
....

Could someone please help with a SQL pattern for simply do this transformation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the unpivot operator as follows:

```
with sample_data as (
    select 12345 as zip_code, '01/01/00' as date_1, '01/08/00' as date_2, '01/15/00' as date_3
)

select up.zip_code, up.date
from sample_data
unpivot(date for col_name in (date_1, date_2, date_3)) up
```

This will produce data like:

[image]

For more information on the unpivot operator check the documentation here:
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#unpivot_operator

Comment: This worked. Thanks Daniel!